# Problema con comparación de arrays en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un curso de programación web *full stack* y me pide la siguiente consigna:

> Escribí la función esPremioMayor la cual recibiendo dos arrays, el primero con los números sorteados y el segundo con los números que jugaste. La función debe devolver el texto "Ganaste" si y solo si los 6 números jugados son iguales a los números sorteados, no importa el orden en el que hayan salido, de lo contrario devolverá la frase "Seguí participando".

Por ejemplo:

```
// Si tuviese los siguientes dos arrays ...
let numerosSorteados = [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ];
let numerosJugados = [ 4 , 12 ,13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ];

// ... y ejecutara mi función ...

esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados);

// ... el resultado sería el siguiente:
"Ganaste"
```

Mi problema es que realicé un código que, al probarlo, en la consola me da bien todos los datos, pero, al pasarlo para que me corrija el trabajo, me da los siguientes errores:

- La función esPremioMayor ejecutada con los siguientes arrays: numerosSorteados [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ] y numerosJugados [ 4 , 12 , 13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ] debería darnos como resultado la frase 'Ganaste'.
- La función esPremioMayor ejecutada con los siguientes arrays: numerosSorteados [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ] y numerosJugados [ 7, 19 , 22 , 36 , 41 , 42 ] debería darnos como resultado la frase 'Seguí participando'.

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados){
  let conteo = 0;
  for (i = 0 ;i < numerosSorteados.length; i++)
  {
   for (f = 0; f < numerosJugados.length; f++)
   {
     if (numerosSorteados [i] == numerosJugados [f])
     {
       conteo ++
     }
   }
  }
  if (conteo == 6)
  {
    console.log("Ganaste"); return true;
  }
  else 
  { 
    console.log("Seguí Participando"); return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema por lo que veo es el retorno de tu función, en la línea:

```
if (conteo == 6){console.log("Ganaste"); return true;}
```

Retornas un booleano, **return true** y el ejercicio necesita que retornes una cadena de texto, por ende debes retornar es la cadena "Ganaste" no el true.

```
if (conteo == 6){console.log("Ganaste"); return "Ganaste";}
```

Fijate el enunciado del problema: la función esPremioMayor debería darnos como resultado la frase 'Ganaste'.

Comment: Ese era el problema, después de 2 o 3 días me siento estúpido por no haberme dado cuenta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
var interseccion = sorteados.filter(value => jugados.includes(value));

if (interseccion.length == 6)
{
   console.log("Ganaste"); 
   return "Ganaste";
}
else 
{ 
   console.log("Seguí Participando"); 
   return "Seguí participando";
}
```

Lo primero que se hace es guardar en el **arreglo intersección** los elementos que son comunes a ambos arreglos.

Posteriormente se retorna **"Ganaste"** si el tamaño del **arreglo intersección** es **6** y en caso contrario se retorna **"Seguí participando"**.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta para simplificar la verificación, pero no debe devolver un valor booleano, sino texto, ya sea `Ganaste`, en lugar de ``true` o `Seguí participando`, en lugar de `false`.

Comment: @Triby, arreglado

Comment: Excelente, ahora sí resuelve el problema.

Comment: Agradezco el resultado, pero en la introducción nunca nos mostraron el .filter, así que no iba a poder utilizarlo para el resultado

Comment: @K4RM0, pero bueno hombre ahora ya sabes que existe el filter y lo puedes usar, no hay que esperar a que te den algo en la escuela para saber que existe. Te agradeceria que si te resulto util la respuesta o aprendiste con ella dieras tu voto positivo, gracias

Comment: es que ya conocía filter jaja, pero como es un mini curso para ver quien entra a la beca no quería utilizar herramientas que no nos hallan dado :)

Comment: Tu sabrás o eso espero

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa es usar [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) y [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) en conjunto para realizar la búsqueda y no basarte en la longitud de números ganadores encontrados para saber si todos los números jugados han sido números ganadores. Ojo, no digo que esté mal, simplemente es una alternativa para solucionar el problema.

Con `indexOf()` realizas la búsqueda, si un número jugado no existe en los números ganadores obtendrás un `-1`. Con `.every()` te aseguras que cada uno de los números jugados hayan sido encontrados y de ser así obtendrás `true`, en caso contrario devolverá `false` para indicarte que existe al menos un número jugado que no ha resultado ganador.

```js
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados) {
  return numerosJugados.every(numeroJugado => numerosSorteados.indexOf(numeroJugado) !== -1) ? 'Ganaste' : 'Seguí participando';
}

console.log(esPremioMayor([ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ], [ 4 , 12 ,13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ]));
console.log(esPremioMayor([ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ], [ 7, 19 , 22 , 36 , 41 , 42 ]));
```

Comment: Conocía el .every, pero en la introducción del curso nunca lo explicaron ni nada, entonces decidí no usarlo por las dudas

Answer (score 0):

acá te dejo una alternativa:

```
function esPremioMayor (sorteados,jugados){

    let suma=0;

        for (i=0; i<sorteados.length; i++){//con el length aseguramos que sea cual sea la longitud de los arrays, esto funcione

            if (sorteados.indexOf(jugados[i])!=-1){//con el indexOf lo que hacemos es buscar si dentro del array sorteados aparece cada número del array jugados, sino aparece entonces devuelve -1, gracias a esto no tenemos que usar el .sort()

                suma=suma+1;
            }
            else {
                suma=suma+0;
            }
          }
        if (suma==6){
            return "Ganaste"
        }
        else {
            return "Seguí participando"
        }
}
```

//Saludos

Comment: Agregas complejidad lineal con tu linea de `suma=suma+0` sugeriria que cuando no haces un calculo matematico, no lo dejes explicito, mejor deja un comentario o algo así